# How to explode column that contains a list of ints into separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with one column that contains a list of 5000 ints in each row. I would like to 'explode' this into 5000 columns (each with one int) for every row. I've tried the str.split(delimeter,expand=True) method -- but this isn't working (of course, I convert the list of ints into a list of strings first). Further, the explode function in pandas does what I require, but exploding into rows and not columns.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `df.col.apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: df.col.apply(pd.Series) worked thank you SO much!

Comment: an update: this is a very slow process for larger dataframes. still looking for a more efficient solution to this